# Defining entity method for rendering as twig blocks

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I want to write my View Layer in a more object oriented way to make use of some benefits of the Object Oriented Model. I was thinking as a start to define a behaviour for my models to be able to specify a way to be rendered by Twig.

I came across [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y5Z5a6QdA-M) that reflected my thoughts well.

For example, let's say I have a User model that I want to display in several places on my website. I would like to define, say, a "Twigable" interface whose methods tell twig how to render this model.

How would I go about implementing this in a scalable manner?

EDIT: I experimented a little. There is not much abstraction right now, including it here might point to what I am after.

I have my model User.php:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Twig\Environment;

class User
{
    private $name;
    private $age;
    private $city;

    public function __construct(string $name, int $age, string $city) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->age = $age;
        $this->city = $city;
    }

    public function render(Environment $twig)
    {
        return $twig->load('model/user.html.twig')->render(['name' => $this->name]);
    }
}
```

I then add to my configuration to pass the twig environment into the render method, *from* my template:

```
twig:
    globals:
        twig_env: '@Twig\Environment'
```

I pass an instance of the User class to the template:

```php
// ... inside the controller action
        $user = new \App\Model\User('John Doe', 40, 'London');

        return $this->render('index.html.twig', [
            'user' => $user,
        ]);
// ...
```

And finally, in the template:

```
{# ... inside index.html.twig #}
{% block body %}
{{ user.render(twig_env) }}
{% endblock %}
{# ... #}
```

Now the twig template no longer needs to "know" what my User class looks like, only that it exists and is displayable.

Is this a good idea?

Comment: An entity should not be responsible on how it should look in the frontend imho

Comment: @DarkBee I was thinking that it can have a general "display" (better naming needed, I know) class, that implements an interface. The entity is then not responsible for **how** it should look, only **that** it should look some way on the front end. The **how** is taken care of by the display-class.

Comment: I've read the updated question. Do note you are putting a lot of constraints on your entities by doing it this way, reducing the  reuseability for other projects, but if that is no concern to you, you even could use the `__toString()` method to return the `render`

Comment: at some point you may want the same entity to be render many times in different pages with different templates. instead, you could make a twig extension and create a function or filter that handles the rendering. eg: user|render('custom')

Comment: @SebastianRadu a macro or an include is better suited for that